# Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, embedded

I have an array of **nearly** sorted values 28 elements long.  I need to find the set of values that sums to a target value provided to the algorithm (or if exact sum cannot be found, the closest sum **Below** the target value).

I currently have a simple algorithm that does the job but it doesn't always find the best match.  It works under ideal circumstances with a specific set of values, but I need a more robust and accurate solution that can handle a wider variety of data sets.

The algorithm must be written in C, not C++, and is meant for an embedded system so keep that in mind.

Here's my current algorithm for reference.  It iterates starting at the highest value available.  If the current value is less than the target sum, it adds the value to the output and subtracts it from the target sum.  This repeats until the sum has been reached or it runs out of values.  It asumes a nearly ascending sorted list.

```
//valuesOut will hold a bitmask of the values to be used (LSB representing array index 0, next bit index 1, etc)

void pickValues(long setTo, long* valuesOut)
{
    signed char i = 27;//last index in array
    long mask = 0x00000001;

    (*valuesOut) = 0x00000000;
    mask = mask<< i;//shift to ith bit
    while(i>=0 && setTo > 0)//while more values needed and available
    {
        if(VALUES_ARRAY[i] <= setTo)
        {
            (*valuesOut)|= mask;//set ith bit
            setTo = setTo - VALUES_ARRAY[i]._dword; //remove from remaining         }
        //decrement and iterate
        mask = mask >> 1;
        i--;
    }
}
```

A few more paramters:

- The array of values is **likely** to be Nearly Sorted ascending, but that cannot be enforced so assume that there is not sorting.  In fact, there may also be duplicate values.
- It is quite possible that the array will hold a set of values that cannot create every sum within its range.  If the exact sum cannot be found, the algorithm should return values that create the next **Lowest** Sum.

Comment: Are the numbers in the set distinct? ie. Can the same number appear more than once?

Comment: @torak No. The same number could appear multiple times

Comment: @torak The values are all positive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is known as the subset sum problem, which is a special case of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Wikipedia is a good starting point for some algorithms.

Comment: It is close to the 0-1 Knapsack Problem but not quite.  The knapsack problem maximizes the number of items packed given a weight limit, given a set of items and their weights.
My goal it to maximize weight subject to the weight limit given a set of items and their weights.

Comment: @CSharperWithJava ... which is known as the subset sum problem, and is a special case of the knapsack problem. You're looking for an approximate subset sum.

Comment: @Karmastan Thanks for the correction.  Yes that is what I am looking for.  Maximize( Sum(w*x) ) <= Target

Comment: Anyway, this problem is equally NP-complete and that means no algorithm can be both, correct and fast. Either it will be incorrect and fast or it will be correct and awfully slow ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, this is same as the optimization version of subset sum problem, which is NP-Complete.

Since you mentioned that you are short in memory and can probably work with approximate solutions (based on your current solution), there are polynomial time approximation algorithms for solving the optimization version of subset sum.

For instance, given an e > 0, there is a polynomial time algorithm which uses O((n*logt)/e) space, (t is the target sum, n is the size of the array) which gives you a subset such that the sum z is no less than 1/(1+e) times the optimal.

i.e If the largest subset sum was y, then the algorithm finds a subset sum z such that

```
z <= y <= (1+e)z
```

and uses space O((n*logt)/e).

Such an algorithm can be found here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/nanda-scribe-3.pdf

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If values are reasonably small, it's a simple dynamic programming (DP). Time complexity would be O(n * target) and memory requirements O(target). If that satisfies you, there're lots of DP tutorials on the web. For example, here the first discussed problem (with couns) is very much like yours (except they allow to use each number more than once):
http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg

**update**
Yep, as other person noted, it's a simple case of knapsack problem.

Comment: The concept is interesting and thank you for pointing me to it.  Unfortuanetly, as I said in the OP this is an embedded application and I don't have O(target) bytes to spare.

Comment: @CSharperWithJava If use bits, you can reduce memory requirements to 'target/8' bytes, but that's pretty much all. Otherwise, you're down to 'approximate' solutions (unless you want to check all 2^28 combinations).