# Largest sum in list less than number

Tags: java

If I have a list of numbers, how do I quickly find the largest sum less than another number. For example, in the list {40,60,22,15,51,22,5,55,32,70} what is the biggest sum less than 50. Thanks for the help, as the only solution I can find is recursive, which seems inefficient. This is for a contest problem which I couldn't solve at the time, and has been frustrating me since.

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer. Get a piece of paper and a pencil. Then write down the steps that you need to solve the problem. Think about how you would do this by hand if someone gave you a list of numbers.

Comment: "as the only solution I can find is recursive, which seems inefficient" Don't worry about efficiency. It is important to write a program that gives the correct solution before worrying about performance.

Comment: I solved it recursively, but I'm looking for something faster

Comment: does your code take time in seconds?

Comment: This looks like a Dynamic Programming problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134275/algorithm-to-pick-values-from-array-that-sum-closest-to-a-target-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the Knapsack Problem, a famous problem in dynamic programming.
Think of it this way: you're a thief and you want to steal as much as possible. Your backpack has a fixed size and you can only take that much. There is a list of items and they each have a certain value and a size. You want to maximize the value stolen. What is the optimal way to pick which items to pick and which not?
So in your case, 50 is the size of the backpack and the numbers are items (here value = size).

Hope this helped!