# Find sum of combination in array element whose sum equal or nearest to number

Tags: php, algorithm

have array of product with reward points as follow

```
$products = array(P1=>40,P2=>40,P3=>63);
```

In system I have 100 reward points to redeem

Want to find sum of combination of element from $products array for maximum utilization of reward points in php

example 1

```
$product = array(P1=>40,P2=>40,P3=>60);

$rewardPoint = 100;

$answer = array($p1=>40,p3=>60);
```

example 2

```
$product = array(P1=>40,P2=>40,P3=>60);

$rewardPoint = 90;

$answer = array($p1=>40,p2=>40);
```

Comment: Have a look at the Knapsack problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: You are looking for Knapsack algorithm. Have a look at https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/knapsack-problem?lang=C%23

Comment: Duplicate of [Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134275/algorithm-to-pick-values-from-array-that-sum-closest-to-a-target-value)