# Calculating additive value match from array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a numeric value and an object containing multiple keyed numeric values. I need to figure out which of the values in the object match the value when added up.

The only solution i could come up with was a linear one:

```js
var values={1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30};
var value=50;
var selected=[];

$.each(values, function(k,v){
    if(v==value)
        selected.push(k);
    $.each(values, function(k2,v2){
        if(v+v2==value) {
            selected.push(k);
        }
    });
});
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This works well for an object with only two matching values (when **value** is 50, for example). But if all three match (set **value** to 60) then it will not yield any results.

Is there a way to solve this **without using a recursive function call**? 
If yes, how?

Comment: what if value was 50 and your array was [15,20,30,35]? What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134275/algorithm-to-pick-values-from-array-that-sum-closest-to-a-target-value)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? For example if you set `value` to `30` you will get 3 outputs...

Comment: @fcalderan The best bet, basically. The software is trying to determine the sets which match. If multiple sets match, it doesn't matter which one is chosen.

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate all subsets of your values array and filter them  based on if they match. Through that you got `O(n^2)` for every length (note that this only works for values having less than 32 elements):

```
const results = [];

for(let i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, values.length); i++){
  const subset = values.filter((_, pos) => (i >> pos) & 1);
  if(subset.reduce((a, b) => a + b) === value)
    results.push(subset);
}
```

Comment: @mhodges nope :)

Comment: This looks promising, and indeed it seems to work. In my use case i won't ever exceed more than 4-5 elements. So this could be a suitable solution. I'll test it thoroughly and accept this as the answer once complete.

Comment: This works very well. Thank you. There is just one problem: my values array is actually an object literal that contains important keys along with each value. But i failed to adapt the code so that it works with an object literal and pushes the corresponding keys into the results array (instead of the actual value as contained in subset).

Comment: Thats another question :)

Comment: You're right. But last time i had such a situation and opened another question, i got flamed. So i rather change my original question :)

Answer (score 2):

First, get all indexes subsets. Then apply a filter over them: this filter retrieves the value from the arr at the indexes and add them up. Then, just output the result.

Advantages, you can use this strategy over any kind of array: of numbers, objects or whatever, just modify the reduce function to retrieve the value from the original array properly.

Hope it helps.

```js
const getAllSubsets =
  theArray => theArray.reduce(
    (subsets, value) => subsets.concat(
      subsets.map(set => [value, ...set])
    ), [[]]);

const arrayOfIndexes = arr => [...Array(arr.length).keys()];

const getIndexSubsets = arr => getAllSubsets(arrayOfIndexes(arr));

// Array of int reduction function
const reduceFunctionOverIntArr = valuesArr =>
  (accumulator, currentIndex) => accumulator + valuesArr[currentIndex];

// Array of custom objs reduction function
const reduceFunctionOverObjArr = valuesArr =>
  (accumulator, currentIndex) => accumulator + valuesArr[currentIndex].val;

const checkValue = (arr, value, reduceFnc) => getIndexSubsets(arr)
  .filter(subset => subset.reduce(reduceFnc(arr), 0) === value);

const intArr = [10, 20, 30];
const customObj = [{val: 10}, {val: 20}, {val: 30}];

// Result over an int array
console.log(checkValue(intArr, 40, reduceFunctionOverIntArr));
console.log(checkValue(intArr, 50, reduceFunctionOverIntArr));
console.log(checkValue(intArr, 60, reduceFunctionOverIntArr));

// result over an object array
console.log(checkValue(customObj, 40, reduceFunctionOverObjArr));
console.log(checkValue(customObj, 50, reduceFunctionOverObjArr));
console.log(checkValue(customObj, 60, reduceFunctionOverObjArr));
```