# How to divide an array into two groups having most appropriate sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You are given an array of integers. You can divide this array into two distinct groups and that groups must have most approapiate sum( the difference beetween the sum of that two groups needs to be as low as possible in modul). The output need to contain the sum of each of two groups. For example: if n = 5 and the array is {2,8,10,1,3} the output needs to be 12 and 12 (12 = 2 + 10 and 12 = 8 + 1 + 3). Is there any faster solution than backtracking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm to pick values from array that sum closest to a target value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134275/algorithm-to-pick-values-from-array-that-sum-closest-to-a-target-value)

Comment: What do you mean by "as low as possible in modul"?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called the [Partition Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) (optimization version) which is NP hard, so you won't find an efficient algorithm that always gives you an exact result. However there are approximate solutions that work very well in practice.

One example is the [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm), which sorts the input array and then fills up the two output arrays, starting with the greatest value, as follows:

```
(1) Put first value to out1
(2) fill up out2 until sum(out2) > sum(out1), exit if no more items
(3) fill up out1 until sum(out1) > sum(out2), exit if no more items
(4) resume with (2)
```